# What does the "++=" sign mean in SBT?

Tags: scala, operators, sbt

I am trying to learn scala. In the Squeryl documentation I have come across this sign `++=`. What does this sign mean? The code was -

```
libraryDependencies  ++=  Seq(
    "org.squeryl" %% "squeryl" % "0.9.5-6",
     yourDatabaseDependency
)
```

Comment: It's part of SBT's twisted and confusingly quasi-Scalaesque DSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't part of Scala itself; it's a method in SBT.

`libraryKeys` is a `SettingKey[Seq[ModuleID]]`, so take a glance at the [API doc for `SettingKey`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/api/#sbt.SettingKey).

`++=` is one of the methods on `SettingKey`. Its return type is `Setting`.

Answer (score 4):

This is simply a method that appends a `Seq` of dependencies to the `libraryDependencies` setting. As compared to `+=`, which appends a single dependency (opposed to a `Seq`).

For more info, [you might want to check out the sbt docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html)

Answer (score 0):

As a general convention in Scala collections, `++=` method takes a collection (right hand side) and puts it into "this" collection (left hand side). SBT uses collections for dependency lists and they are no exception.